# Plotly working locally but not on Shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, shiny-server, r-plotly

I am trying to create a line graph with two y-axises. The x-axis is the date and both of the y-axises are continuous data. I have working code to do this. It works perfectly, however when I push that to my shiny server (on Ubuntu) I get an error saying that 'x' must be a list. Not sure why this works locally but not on my shiny server.

server.R

```
dataset <- reactive({
      infile <- input$datafile
      if (is.null(infile)) {
        return(NULL)
      }
      else {read_excel(infile$datapath)}
    })

output$plot_data <- renderPlotly({
        # Bring in the data 
        data <- subset(dataset(), select = c(input$date, input$var1, input$var2))
        date <- data[[input$date]]
        y_var1 <- data[[input$var1]]
        y_var2 <- data[[input$var2]]

        y1 <- list(tickfont = list(color = "blue"),
                    side = "left",
                    title = input$var1
                  )
        y2 <- list(tickfont = list(color = "green"),
                    overlaying = "y",
                    side = "right",
                    title = input$var2
                  )
        plot <- plot_ly() %>%
              add_lines(x = date, 
                        y = y_var1, 
                        name = input$var1,
                        line = list(color = "blue")) %>%
              add_lines(x = date, 
                        y = y_var2, 
                        name = input$var2, 
                        yaxis = "y2",
                        line = list(color = "green")) %>%
              layout(title = "Data Over Time",
                     yaxis = y1,
                     yaxis2 = y2
                    )

        plot
```

ui.R

```
plotlyOutput('plot_data', height = 500)
```

Here is some sample data that has a date column and two continuous columns.

```
Date           Impressions   Sessions
01/01/2019     34124114      11234323
01/02/2019     43523523      12341244
01/03/2019     56547634      11124324
01/04/2019     65756844      12341234
01/05/2019     32454355      11412432
01/06/2019     23543664      12342412
01/07/2019     23534262      12341244
01/08/2019     12341324      12341234
01/09/2019     34645623      23412341
01/10/2019     64364363      12342123
01/11/2019     24114124      13412342
01/12/2019     23411242      13423442
01/13/2019     24124124      11234242
01/14/2019     42141132      12342144
```

Comment: Would help to know the data. Not reproducible due to missing dataset()

Comment: The app loads in any dataset that has a Date column and then at least 2 other continuous columns. I can add in the dataset() function and provide some data.